# Hibernate: create SQL Server 2012 database table in non-default schema

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use Hibernate to create a table in a SQL Server 2012 database.

I set a number of properties in my Java project's persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" />
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="auto" />
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
```

... and set the database connection details in when UI create my data source, which is done in a configuration Java class:

```
dataSource.setDriverClassName(myDriver); // com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
dataSource.setUrl(myUrl); // jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;DatabaseName=dbname
dataSource.setUsername(myUser);
dataSource.setPassword(myPwd);
```

In the Java class, I also set the default schema when I create the Java Persistence entity manager factory:

```
final Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "mySchema");
entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
```

The Java domain class has been annotated as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
public class MyTable {
...
}
```

The schema called "mySchema" has been created in the SQL Server database and authorization has been granted to the user specified in the data source.

When I try and run the functionality which should create the table as part of the first run (and populate it appropriately), I get the following error message:

```
SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'mySchema.mytable'
```

... and the table has not been created in the schema.

The Hibernate SQL looks like this:

```
select  alias0_.ID as alias1_0_0_
... other columns...
from    mySchema.mytable alias0_
where   alias0_.ID=?
```

I'm using version 1.0.0.Final of the hibernate-jpa-2.1-api JAR in my Java project.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Have you added `<mapping class=com.mymodel.MyTable >` in persistence.xml file?

Comment: The work-around is to set the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value to "none" in the persistence.xml file and create the database tables myself.

Comment: But this setting will not generate tables.

Comment: @Amogh Yes, I understand that but it's an acceptable work-around in my case.